# Valid distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

If $N(0,\sigma^2)$ is the Gaussian distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$, is $pN(0,\sigma^2)$ a valid distribution ? $p$ is a constant and $0\le p\le 1$.

Comment: It will fail normalization unless $p = 1$.

Comment: Can you explain why it fails normalization makes it not a valid distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer this, I have to guess what you mean by the question.  I have *two* guesses.  Assuming one of the two, the answer is "no", and assuming the other, it's "yes".

The normal distribution assigns a probability to each interval from a number $a$ to a number $b$.  Let's say $X$ is a random variable whose probability distributino is $N(0,\sigma^2)$.  Then $\Pr(a<X<b)$ is determined by that distribution and which numbers $a$ and $b$ are.

If you mean by $pN(0,\sigma^2)$ a measure that just multiplies $\Pr(a<X<b)$ by $p$ and says that's the "probability" of some random variable being between $a$ and $b$, then the answer is "no", because it would say $\Pr(-\infty<X<\infty)=p$, whereas any probability distribution of a real-valued random variable $X$ would say $\Pr(-\infty<X<\infty)=1$.

On the other hand, I wonder if by $pN(0,\sigma^2)$ you might mean the distribution of $pX$, where $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.  In that case, one would say $pX\sim N(0,p^2\sigma^2)$.  And that is a valid probability distribution.

Of course, it's possible that both of my guesses are wrong.

**Later note:** From comments it seems my first guess was right.  So this is not a probability distribution.  The density of the $N(0,\sigma^2)$ distribution is

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2\  {}}} \exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\  \sigma} \exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$

And as with all probability densities on the real line, we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx=1.$$

But

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty pf(x)\,dx \ne 1\text{ unless }p=1$$

so it's not a probability density unless $p=1$.  It is, however the density of an absolutely continuous measure.

Comment: My meaning is if we consider $f(x) = exp(-x^2)/(2\pi \sigma^2)$ we can say that $f(x)$ is a valid PDF. So I dont know whether we can say $pf(x)$ is a valid PDF.

Comment: In that case, my first guess is right, and this is not a probability distribution.  The density of the $N(0,\sigma^2)$ distribution is $f(x)=\exp(-x^2/(2\sigma^2))/\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2\ {}}$ $=\exp(-x^2/(2\sigma^2))/(\sqrt{2\pi{}}\ \sigma)$.  And as with all probability densities on the real line, we have $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx=1$.  But $\int_{-\infty}^\infty pf(x)\,dx \ne 1$ unless $p=1$, so it's not a probability density unless $p=1$.  It is, however the density of an absolutely continuous measure.